# Текст в canvas (js)

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

как получить текст из input'ов?
и как сделать, чтобы он был поверх изображения?
сделала два canvas, изображение показывает, поставила двум канвасам различные z-индексы, но пробный текст не виден.

фрагмент html:

```
<div><label for="line-top">Top line</label>
<input type="text" id="line-top"></div>
<div><label for="line-bottom">Bottom line</label>
<input type="text" id="line-bottom"></div>
```

пыталась что то своими силами набросать на js(новичок):

```
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
context2.style.zIndex = "1";

drawText = function(){
  context2.font = "45pt Impact";
  context2.fillStyle = "white";
  context2.strokeStyle = "black";
  context2.lineWidth = 2;
  context2.textAlign = "center";
  context2.fillText("HELLO WORLD", canvas2.width/2, canvas2.height/5);
  context2.strokeText("HELLO WORLD", canvas2.width/2, canvas2.height/5);
};


function getLines (){
  var inputTop = document.getElementsByTagName("line-top");
  var inputBottom = document.getElementsByTagName("line-top");
  var top = inputTop.elements.value;
  var bottom = inputBottom.elements.value;
}
```

и еще, почему так не работает?

```
var top = "HELLO";

  context.font = "45pt Impact";
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(top, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/5);
  context.strokeText(top, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/5);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Получение текстов из input:**

```
let text = document.getELementById("input_id").value;
```

**Рисование текста:**

```
document.getELementById ("canvas").getContext ("2d").fillText (text, text_x, text_y);
```

Что бы поместить текст поверх изображения достаточно сначала нарисовать изображение, а позже текст.

```
ctx.clearRect()=>ctx.drawImage()=>ctx.fillTect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример. Просто рисуем текст на логотипе SO с помощью canvas и jquery.

```js
var ctx = $('#my-canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png';
    img.onload = function(){ ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);}
});

$( "#hello-button" ).click(function() {
    ctx.font = "24px serif";
    ctx.strokeText($("#line-top").val(), 50, 100); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="line-top" value="на русском — это фича, а не баг!">
<input type="submit" id="hello-button"> 
</form>
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```